# How To Query Cosmos DB Collection From C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, c#-4.0, azure-cosmosdb

getting the below error while connecting to cosmosdb from C#.

The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign:

```
'get

    wed, 07 aug 2019 13:20:12 gmt

    ActivityId: 01489e82-0586-44d0-878d-0cc8cee22852, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.5.1, Windows/10.0.15063 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.4.0
```

---

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace DeviceCount
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly string EndpointUri = "aaaa";
        private static readonly string PrimaryKey = "bbb";
        private static readonly string DBName = "ccc";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
            var currentEpochTime = (int)currentTime.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;

            var currentTimeMinusOneH = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);

            var currentEpochTimeMinusOneH = (int)currentTimeMinusOneH.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;

            ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy();
            connectionPolicy.ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway;

            using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), PrimaryKey, connectionPolicy))
            {

                client.OpenAsync().Wait();


                var response = client.CreateDocumentQuery
               (UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DBName, "ddddd"),
                    "SELECT value count(c.id) FROM ddddd c where c._ts between " + currentEpochTime + " and " + currentEpochTimeMinusOneH).ToList();

                var document = response.First();
                Console.WriteLine($"Id:{document.id}");
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the target API of your Cosmos DB account?

Answer (score 0):

Seems issue is in the token as per the error you need a valid signature hash for the master token in the authorization header to perform REST calls against Cosmosdb.

The signature hash is composed of the REST verb, resource type, resource id and the UTC DateTime of the operation.  You will need to construct a new signature hash for every **[`operation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN)**.

Comment: OP is using .Net SDK which should compute the signature hash and make the REST API call. I don't think it is needed to compute this hash in code.

Comment: I have added the complete code in my question. I am trying to connect from a console app.@GauravMantri,@Sajeetharan

Comment: Follow the instructions and sample code here https://cosmosdb.github.io/labs/dotnetV2/technical_deep_dive/03-querying_the_database_using_sql.html#implement-cross-partition-queries